# My IPv6 on Windows 2012 R2 can receive incoming pings but I cant make outgoing pings

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6

Windows 2012 R2 server. I have added the IPv6 `2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe2c:a546` with Google Ipv6 public DNS.

Now I can ping it from a remote machine just fine. However, when remote desktop into the machine, it says "Destination host unreachable." for `ping www.google.com -6` , the same error for directly pinging Google ipv6 `ping 2607:f8b0:400a:801::2004` , nor reaching any other sites with ipv6 enable. A test http://test-ipv6.com/ on browser revealing "No IPv6 address detected " I am pretty sure the address was added correctly and shows up on `ipconfig`. I can even run services on it. Just that its ok receiving incoming traffic on the address remotely but the server cant communicate on ipv6 from the inside.

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Where can you ping it from?

Comment: if I ping the server from my home machine or another remote server, the ping is fine.

Comment: If remote desktop inside, I can see the ip in ipconfig setup correctly, But I cant piing any site. It says "Destination not reachable" . Even already applied https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852  "Re-enable Ipv6" . Any idea why it only taking incoming ipv6 traffic but cant make outgoing ?

Comment: I will reframe my question, where can you ping your server? from inside your network? Is it the same ISP? What is the source address from where you are pinging the server? Can you try pinging google ipv6 dns **2001:4860:4860::8888**.

Comment: How did you set up IPv6 in Windows?

Comment: @Anirudh Malhotra  when I ping the Ip remotely, its on different networks. Home network is about thousand miles away from the server or other servers even in different countries. When I remote desktop, I cant ping any site with -6 switch. See the screenshot of your requested ping https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a2jijmrxqkq2pr/failedpings.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @Michael Hampton this is how I set it up. The only and same way working everywhere else https://www.dropbox.com/s/19nv4uz1z16ohv2/setup.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You do not have a default gateway here. Can you also give **ipconfig /all**

Comment: have added the gateway **fe80::1**  I removed it while testing around .  Just added it again and restarted but no help. SS of **ipconfig /all** as below https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsfhknvz3js36vn/ipconfigall.jpg?dl=0 tks

Comment: If you are able to ping the gateway, and there is no ipv6 conflict there shouldn't be a problem. Only reason i can think of is ISP blocking your traffic(only outgoing apparently and strangely)

Comment: i can not ping the gateway nor the google DNS ipv6 with the same error. I can only ping the ISP's DNS **2600:3c00::5** . Changing from google dns to the ISP DNS **2600:3c00::5** and **2600:3c00::6** does not resolve anything, same behavior.

Comment: On Linode, you should have "Obtain an IPv6 address automatically" set. You should not attempt to set it manually.

Comment: Did that. same problem. Also if I have it on automatically. How do I add multiple ipv6s later ? Planning to have about 5-10 ipv6 on that server. tks